# Proteger WebService NUSOAP

Tags: php, .net, web-service

Desenvolvi um serviço WSDL por meio da biblioteca NUSOAP. A intenção é fazer com que o Web Service possa ser acessado tanto por aplicações PHP como na plataforma **.NET**, no entanto, gostaria de adicionar uma segurança no acesso ao WebService para que, somente aplicações permitidas possam acessá-lo.